# Установка matplotlib под Windows

Tags: python, windows, установка

Можно ли добавить библиотеку `matplotlib` без её установки? Если из этой библиотеки нужна только функция pyplot.

Есть ли вариант, чтобы просто скопировать нужные файлы в папку библиотек `python`?

Comment: Если проблемы с установкой, то опишите проблему, логи приложите. А если не с установкой, то зачем игнорировать штатный установщик пакетов?

Comment: pyplot это не просто функция, это модуль, который связан со всеми остальными модулями в библиотеке matplotlib. Соответственно вам все равно понадобится вся библиотека matplotlib.

Comment: Дело в том, что установка для меня несколько странная. В части открытости. Не смог разобраться что и куда она устанавливает)

Comment: А вы как устанавливаете? под windows или под linux?  В виртуальное окружение?

Comment: Устанавливаю под Windows

Comment: вы уже выполнили команду `py -m pip install matplotlib`? Что вы видите в результате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скачайте файлы отсюда https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
2. Переместите папку ./lib/matplotlib в папку вашего проекта
3. `import matplotlib` подхватит модуль из этой папки без установки

Comment: Не работает. Пишет, что модуль `six` отсутствует.

Comment: Модуль `six` это отдельный модуль, его тоже таким способом поставить можно (https://github.com/JioCloud/python-six), либо по-обычному (`pip install six`)

Comment: Вообще, рекомендую ставить модули установкой, потому как во время установки они самостоятельно устанавливают зависимости вроде `six`, плюс так легче их обновлять

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете в Python 3.x в виндовс, то заходите в папку в которой он питон лежит, заходите в скрипт вызываете командную строку и из папки скрипт запускаете команду

```
pip.exe install matplotlib
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хоть тут и ошибка он всётаки  не лёг на python в папке которой был пробел, я переустановил питон, вот так `C:\Python37`